# Why Won't The Right Column Stay A Fixed Width And How To Fix?

Tags: html, css

I created a jsfiddle example here

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmazqt4q/5/

But when I try to fix the right column, it doesn't stay a fixed width. I know that with the same code if I put it on the left side and fix that, it'll stay fixed fine. Been awhile since I've played with css so trying to refresh and have gotten frustrated with this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

If you need the code, here it is

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
           header
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="topBar">
            Top bar
        </div>
        <div id="leftColumn" class="column">
            Content
        </div>
        <div id="rightColumn" class="column">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;
    font: 13px/17px Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
div#header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
}
div#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
div#content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #B4C4EA;
    height: 87%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
}
div#footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
}
div#topBar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #444;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.column {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}
div#leftColumn {
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 83.88%;
}
div#rightColumn {
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 1.25em;
}
```

Comment: @j08691 In the JSFiddle link?

Comment: _when I try to fix the right column, it doesn't stay fixed_. What do you mean? I don't see any `position: fixed`?

Comment: Updated with the code. And I tested the same code on its own separate page.

And I meant the width to be fixed.

Comment: A.. the `width` to be fixed. Then you have to use `px` insteada of `em`.

Comment: If the `.leftColumn` is working with `83.88%` then the `.rightColumn` needs to have some capacity of the remaining `100%` of the total width - so  `16%` and some change. It could have a `min/max` "fixed" width, but it would cause it to flow to the next line if it either exceeds the remaining `16.12%` that the `.leftColumn` isn't taking up. Setting `box-sizing: border-box;` could help things run a bit smoother and more precise as well with these kinds of layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could float the right column and give the `overflow:hidden` property to the left. If you have the right column come before the left in your markup, the left column will fill the remaining width.

**HTML**

```
<div id="topBar">Top bar</div>
<div id="rightColumn" class="column">Content</div>
<div id="leftColumn" class="column">Content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.column {
    float: right;
}
div#rightColumn {
    width:50px;
}
div#leftColumn {
    float:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmazqt4q/6/)

---

Or, display your columns as table cells, this way would require you to have a container for your columns:

**HTML**

```
<div class="columns">
    <div id="leftColumn" class="column">Content</div>
    <div id="rightColumn" class="column">Content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.columns {
    display:table;
    width:100%
}
.column {
    display:table-cell;
}
div#rightColumn {
    width:50px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmazqt4q/7/)

Comment: Well, that sorta works, but the left column still has issues from playing around with it. Won't stay the width up to the right column

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue you have? Which option are you working with?

Comment: The second option with the tables works better. Forgot about table layout tbh (haven't played with that since like..early 2000s or late 1990s with the actual <table> tag lol).

Thanks :)

Comment: No problem :) Glad to have helped.

Comment: well, apparently playing with this styling option works in all browsers but Chrome when you start using input elements :P damn. Hope chrome fixes it, but time to figure out how to fix it for Chrome. 

Basically, inputs will mess up the height and add a lot to it.